# How to upload image to server automatically using Javascript

Tags: jquery, html

I need to upload image to server using input type file in html. i have  known file to upload automatically. how can i upload that image  without popping the file select dialog box.

Ex: My image file is in C:\ProjectFiles\Images\profile.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.

The author of a web page cannot choose a file from the visitor's system. If they could, it would be a major security problem.

If you need that functionality, don't use a webpage. Use a browser extension or some standalone software.